# Ember component's template issue with jQuery sortable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, ember.js

I'm trying to create a simple Ember component that wraps [jQuery UI Sortable](https://jqueryui.com/sortable/) plugin. Unfortunately I have an issue with component's template when `sortable` is cancelled and model is updated manually. It looks like the DOM does not reflect the state of the model. I'm not able to find why.

I've created [JS Bin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/bazowuliva/edit?html,js,output) to present this issue. When you change item position, the first one in the group should be removed. Unfortunately it works randomly.

What's wrong with this code?

Comment: I don't have an answer to your question but i can at least suggest the POV with which you should consider analysing your situation. The jQuery UI Sortable plugin relies on direct DOM manipulation which would happen as callbacks which are registered by it fire on mouse events users do. Ember on other side uses HTMLbars which also has DOM manipulation logic which is far more sophisticated and should be dived into to understand such behaviour. What you should do is to avoid direct DOM manipulation and mutate the `content` array on the component. That is Ember way of doing things.

Comment: I think i should also add that if you want to get it right from the start you should `unbound` the `content` array before you actually mutate so you won't end up in a data-binding hell.

Comment: @canufeel you are right that's the DOM issue. When I simulate refresh in the component like in this [JS Bin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/huciqinoho/edit?html,js,output) then it works. However I think there must have been some Ember way to do it. Maybe it's a Glimmer issue which can not do a proper diff after DOM has been mutated by jQuery UI?

Comment: actually as of my understanding how Glimmer works - it first checks out what is the input for the rendering engine. The input in your case would be `content` array and you iterate over it's `items`. The key rule here is that if input which is `content` or any `item` changes then the rerender should happen. The trick with sortable is that it doesn't change `item`s not `content` it just changes the DOM. The glimmer itself won't observe the DOM it observes the input variables so from a Glimmer side nothing actually have changed which is wrong in the first place.

Comment: even if you fix the sortable side of things there would be no way to let Glimmer be aware of the change without mutating the underlying array so this might introduce some weird bugs in the future as soon as you would want to add some more features to it.

Comment: @canufeel thanks for taking your time to answer me. I agree with you but on the other side I call `cancel` event on the jQuery sortable UI after user stops manipulating the item - it should (as fair as I understand) brings DOM back to the initial state. Then I mutate the `content` by removing its first element - it should trigger re-rendering of the component but as we've already noticed it does not do it correctly. I'm trying to understand what's going on here and how should I write jQuery UI wrappers that follows Ember way.

Comment: jQuery UI uses DOM manipulation which is not an Ember way in a first place. You can write your own plugin or find existing one which would mimic the jQuery UI sortable behaviour relying on data mutation. This is a way to go. In your case the array itself mutates but DOM manipulations you make break something inside Glimmer so it can't yield the correct diff even though the input data is changed. It is not very clear what might be the problem here as even returning DOM pre-sortable state using `$().sortable('destroy')` and removing unnecessary class leftovers after it still breaks Glimmer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your JS Bin sortable component:

```
App.MyListComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  tagName: 'ul',

  didInsertElement() {
    let opts = {};
    opts.update = this.updateList.bind(this);
    this.$().sortable(opts);
  },

  updateList() {
    this.$().sortable('cancel');
    Ember.run.next(() => {
      this.get('content').removeAt(0);
    });
  }
});
```

And then this is your JS Bin [updated](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/resuhuderu/edit?html,js,output) with code from the [ember-ui-sortable repo](https://github.com/12StarsMedia/ember-ui-sortable) to the following:

```
App.MyListComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  tagName: 'ul',

  uiOptions: [
    'axis',
    'containment',
    'cursor',
    'cursorAt',
    'delay',
    'disabled',
    'distance',
    'forceHelperSize',
    'forcePlaceholderSize',
    'grid',
    'handle',
    'helper',
    'opacity',
    'placeholder',
    'revert',
    'scroll',
    'scrollSensitivity',
    'scrollSpeed',
    'tolerance',
    'zIndex'
  ],

  destroySortable: Ember.on('willDestroyElement', function() {
    this.$().sortable('destroy');
  }),

  initSortable: Ember.on('didInsertElement', function () {
    let opts = {};

    ['start', 'stop'].forEach((callback) => {
      opts[callback] = Ember.run.bind(this, callback);
    });

    this.$().sortable(opts);

    this.get('uiOptions').forEach((option) => {
      this._bindSortableOption(option);
    });
  }),

  contentObserver: Ember.observer('content.[]', function () {
    Ember.run.scheduleOnce('afterRender', this, this._refreshSortable);
  }),

  move(oldIndex, newIndex) {
    let content = this.get('content');
    let mutate = this.getWithDefault('mutate', true);
    let item = content.objectAt(oldIndex);

    if (content && mutate) {
      content.removeAt(oldIndex);
      content.insertAt(newIndex, item);
    }

    if(!mutate){
      this.attrs.moved(item, oldIndex, newIndex);
    }

  },

  start(event, ui) {
    ui.item.data('oldIndex', ui.item.index());
  },

  stop(event, ui) {
    const oldIndex = ui.item.data('oldIndex');
    const newIndex = ui.item.index();

    this.move(oldIndex, newIndex);
  },

  _bindSortableOption: function(key) {
    this.addObserver(key, this, this._optionDidChange);

    if (key in this) {
      this._optionDidChange(this, key);
    }

    this.on('willDestroyElement', this, function() {
      this.removeObserver(key, this, this._optionDidChange);
    });
  },

  _optionDidChange(sender, key) {
    this.$().sortable('option', key, this.get(key));
  },

  _refreshSortable() {
    if (this.isDestroying) { return; }
    this.$().sortable('refresh');
  }
});
```

As you'll see, there is quite a bit extra going on versus your original, so you can have a look at what you missed and hopefully this helps you.
It might be a good idea to install that component addon via ember-cli, but also have a look at competing solutions like [ember-sortable](https://github.com/jgwhite/ember-sortable) and others first by using something like [ember-observer](https://emberobserver.com/?query=sortable).

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I don't think missing observer is an issue here. I actually started with the code from your plugin (I've just added `cancel` call after user stops manipulating the item and model update call) then I started to simplify it bit by bit till the the code that is in the JSBIN.